# How to convert a string (in three separate columns) to a timestamp(one column) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, string-to-datetime

Hi i'm a new coder and messed up on my sql table. Instead of storing my date with a timestamp I made the date in three separate columns: day, month, and year. I now realized that I need these in a timestamp. So I can perform more complicated queries.

Here is what I need the UPDATE to look like:

```
UPDATE coding_tracker SET coded_at = column(day)"/"column(month_number(month))"/"column(year);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have been able to make this much so far UPDATE coding_tracker SET coded_at = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT());

Comment: Is your month column a string or a number? If a string, is it short or long month names? If a number, does it start with 0 or 1 for January?

Comment: While you're changing this, it's a good time to ask yourself if you are really 100% sure you need a timestamp. Timestamps have a limited range of dates - they cannot represent any year before 1970 nor after 2038. The alternative to timestamp with just a date in it is a "date" (any year  from 0000 to 9999 goes) , or a datetime (can also contain the time, not just the date).

Comment: my months are names that are capitled ex: November

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your columns are called day, month_number and year, this query should work:

```
UPDATE coding_tracker SET coded_at = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('/', day, month_number, year), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

In the case where your `month` column is a name, you can change `%m` in the above query to `%b` for short month names (`Jan..Dec`) or `%M` for long month names (`January..December`) e.g. for long names:

```
UPDATE coding_tracker SET coded_at = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('/', day, month, year), '%d/%M/%Y')
```

Documentation about formats for [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) can be found in the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) section of the MySQL manual.

Comment: thank you, it works except i need my months to be converted from a string to a number

Comment: Are your months short or long names?

Comment: they are full length, and the first letter is capital

Comment: i am getting this error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: also i have never seen the CONCAT_WS function what is the _WS for

Comment: @MasonHorder sorry that was a typo, one too many `)`s. I've removed it in my edit.

Comment: [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) stands for `CONCAT With Separator`, you specify the separator between each value at the beginning. It's shorthand for writing `CONCAT(day, '/', month, '/', year)`